# sfdx:source:pull gave the following error

Tags: salesforcedx

When I try to pull from a scratch org to my local I got the below error

[image]

But when I checked the status as > sfdx force:source:status -u , Then I can see there are some remote changes like below in the image and also some unknown files like ProfileSessionSetting, ProfilePasswordPolicy. Anyone has any idea to remove it from the remote?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding these metadata types to your force.ignore file?

Comment: @John Towers where can I find this file? I couldn't find this file in the Intellij.

Comment: You'll need to create it in your project's top-level directory. The format is documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm

Comment: @Joh Towers.. I will try your solution. But when I create a new DX project with new configuration I can able to work with. But do you have any idea about how those files are generated in remote?

Comment: They're related to changes to the session and password settings for profiles. So some change to a profile is causing them to be created.

Comment: FWIW, I hit these errors after creating a site and modifying the public user profile to add a couple of Apex classes. Took me a while to find this answer!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding following lines to `.forceignore` file solved the issue:

```
**/*SessionSetting*
**/*PasswordPolicy*
*SessionSetting*
*PasswordPolicy*
```

[Read](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm) to know more about `.forceignore`

---

Credits: [John Towers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12645/john-towers).